# How to uninstall or remove MySQL database client library

Tags: server, dpkg, mysql, client

I have totally Uninstall mysql  from system. But

MySQL database client library **till mysql client library exit at system**

Wherever  run the command  `sudo dpkg -l 'libmysqlclient*'`

**Getting the result:**

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
rc  libmysqlclient 5.5.49-0ubun amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libmysqlclient 5.5.49-0ubun i386         MySQL database client library
```

that mean   **MySQL database client library** still exit at system.

**So i want to know how it will be remove from system**

Answer (score 0):

It will be resolved by the below command

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
```

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how and why to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)